# ObjC using blocks with progress delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, objective-c-blocks

From the next blog http://thejoeconwayblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/blocks-or-delegation/

one of the main differences between delegate callbacks and blocks is "Process vs. Results"

My question is:
I want to use blocking for starting a process with completion, but during the process i want to notify the caller with the process steps. is it better to use **delegate callbacks** or **blocks with a delegate callback only for my progress notification** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no better or worse. Both alternatives will do the job.

Commonly blocks are more elegant and demand less boilerplate code. On the other hand, delegation, from my point of view, is often easier to understand when reading someone else's code.

I do not see the point in combining both, delegation and blocks - I personally would refrain from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some observations on Delegates and Blocks**

1. If an object has more than one distinct event, use delegation.
2. If an object is a singleton, we can't use delegation.
3. If the object is calling back for additional information, we'll probably use delegation.
4. Delegate callbacks are more process oriented and blocks are more results oriented.
5. If you need to be informed along the way of a multi-step process, you'll probably want to use delegation.
6. If you just want the information you are requesting (or details about a failure to get the information), you should use a block.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is a simple and powerful pattern in which one object acts on behalf of another object.

Blocks are self contained piece of code that have access to the local and parameter of calling method.Block enhance the readability and maintainability of code.